# QML Window opacity doesn't work when fullscreen

Tags: qt, qml, qt-quick

I've experienced a strange problem: when a QML `Window` is fullscreen, its `opacity` property doesn't work, so the window stay opaque. When the window isn't fullscreen (e.g. maximized), it works properly.

Do you have any ideas how to deal with this problem?
In fact, I want to animate fullscreen window fading in.

**The code:**

*main.qml*

```
import QtQuick 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.1
import QtQuick.Window 2.1

Window {
    visible: true
    visibility: "FullScreen"

    opacity: 0.5

    Text {
        id: text
        text: "Hello World"
        font.pointSize: 36
        color: "#333"
    }
}
```

*main.cpp*

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:///main.qml")));

    return app.exec();
}
```

I use Qt 5.3 on Windows 8.1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the age-old bug of the Qt/Win combination - windows with an OpenGL context, can't be made transparent without employing trickery. The solution is to embed your QML application in a `QQuickWidget` and make that transparent and full-screen. There also exists another workaround (using the 'DWM' API, which is nonportable -  you can read about it in the bug description).

https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-28214

Comment: I've got the same issue on mac. And with the modern metal backend the QQuickWidget hack is no longer a solution for me. Any ideas how I could get round this?

Comment: I have no idea, this was ages ago and I am no longer trying to work around this. Maybe you could file a new bug with a small test case using the metal backend? From my memory, the `QQuickWidget` hack should work no matter what backend is used. If it isn't, you have found a bug in Qt itself.

Comment: It‘s interesting. If you call show on a quickwidget with a metal backend it chucks out ab assertion „quickwidget only supports an OpenGL backend“ do I guess it’s by design

Comment: write a bug report, don't be afraid :) and try the same thing under linux.

Comment: Thanks - I made a bug report https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-111313